# React Native (IOS) - Not able to press on components after closing a modal

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, mobile

### Description

I'm not able to press on other components after closing a modal

### React Native version:

0.63.0

### Steps To Reproduce

- After loading the screen, try to interact with the components
- Open the popup by clicking in the bottom button
- Try to interact with the components again

The video reproducing the issue: https://streamable.com/1bb89k

### Expected Results

The components should stay interactable after closing the modal

### Link to the repository:

https://github.com/LauraBeatris/bill-splitting

### Modal

https://github.com/LauraBeatris/bill-splitting/blob/master/src/contexts/popup/PopupContainer.ts

```
  <PopupProvider value={payload}>
      <Popup
        isOpen={popupState.isOpen}
        hidePopup={hidePopup}
        handleOnShow={handleOnShow}
        handleOnHide={handleOnHide}
      >
        {
          Component && (
            <Component
              hidePopup={hidePopup}
              showPopup={showPopup}
              {...componentProps}
            />
          )
        }
      </Popup>

      {children}
    </PopupProvider>
```

Comment: Sorry, putting the link to the repo is not worth it. I added a snippet of the modal component with the current props that I'm passing.

Comment: Can you also add the snippet of the parent component? What renders the modal?

Comment: Sure! Just added. There's a context which renders the modal